# Color transparency in Inkscape palette (.gpl)

Tags: colors, gimp, inkscape

I am using color palette in Inkscape, through the .gpl file format (GIMP uses the same format, according to DuckDuckGo) :

```
GIMP Palette
Name: Character/Dragon/Magma
Columns: 3
#
241  33  33  Body
253 221  45  Scales
114  57  33  Hair
 67  34  20  Internal hair
156  57 217  Eyes
 25   7  36  Pupill
  0   0   0  Lines
251 249 240  Teeth
249 246 225  Teeth between
```

All are RGB colors, but I now need to add a color with transparency, so a RGBA color:

`249 246 225 180 Eyes (specular)`

I intuitively tried turning all existing colors into RGBA and use `Columns: 4`

```
GIMP Palette
Name: Character/Dragon/Magma
Columns: 4
#
241  33  33 255 Body
253 221  45 255 Scales
114  57  33 255 Hair
 67  34  20 255 Internal hair
156  57 217 255 Eyes
 25   7  36 255 Pupill
  0   0   0 255 Lines
251 249 240 255 Teeth
249 246 225 255 Teeth between
```

But nope, Inkscape ignores transparency and names colors as `255 Body` (so it keep thinking they are RGB colors)

**How can I add a color with a transparency (alpha value) to this Inkscape palette?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transparency isn't specified in the GIMP palette format, because colors do not have a transparency by themselves in GIMP - instead, this is determined by paint tool settings, layer transparency, partial selection, ...

If you want to extend the palette format, then you will also have to do the coding in the applications you're using (Inkscape, for example) to recognize the changed format.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when exporting JASC-PAL format from Aseprite. It doesn't seem to support alpha. However, GIMP palette format does, at least when used with Aseprite. Maybe Inkscape does too?

All I had to do was add the fourth column, as you did, and specify `Channels: RGBA`.

Before:

```
GIMP Palette
#
  0   0   0 Untitled
  1   1   1 Untitled
  2   2   2 Untitled
  3   3   3 Untitled
  4   4   4 Untitled
  5   5   5 Untitled
  6   6   6 Untitled
  7   7   7 Untitled
  8   8   8 Untitled
  9   9   9 Untitled
 10  10  10 Untitled
 11  11  11 Untitled
 12  12  12 Untitled
...
```

After:

```
GIMP Palette
Channels: RGBA
#
  0   0   0   0 Untitled
  1   1   1   1 Untitled
  2   2   2   2 Untitled
  3   3   3   3 Untitled
  4   4   4   4 Untitled
  5   5   5   5 Untitled
  6   6   6   6 Untitled
  7   7   7   7 Untitled
  8   8   8   8 Untitled
  9   9   9   9 Untitled
 10  10  10  10 Untitled
 11  11  11  11 Untitled
 12  12  12  12 Untitled
...
```

Note:

- There's a tab, not a space, between the last number and the color name (all "Untitled" in my case).
- My colors are intentionally boring shades of grey. Any RGBA values can be used. They needn't match.